# Configuration script for WS02 Identity Server

Tags: scripting, wso2, identity, wso2-identity-server

I need to install WSO2 Identity Server in several machines with a custom configuration (some service providers, roles, user datasource etc. etc.). I have seen that almost everything can be done using the webservices exposed, but I'm looking for something else.

Is it available a tool to collect these configurations in a sort of script and launch it on a new created istance or the only way is to create something that call the webservices?

Comment: So do you have those configurations already installed in 1 IS instance and you need to export them and add them to a new instance,
or are you looking for a way to avoid repeating the web service calls?

Comment: I have already different IS instances, but when I have to modify something on a single instance then I have to replicate to the others, using the web interface. Using a script I would launch it on instance 1,2,3...

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ability to create a cluster of IS instances, everything you do through the UI (Management Console) will be automatically replicated/synced with the other IS instances. You can create a cluster following the below link.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+Identity+Server+5.1.0